# installing scipy on cygwin / win7

Tags: python, scipy, cygwin, cython

just getting into python and need to install some number crunching packages, amongst them scipy in the cygwin environment running on windows 7 machines. NOTE : i do NOT want to remake the entire release or the master, i just want to install scipy for use. the scipy web site says i should just be able to install this using pip. however, when i try to install it :

```
$  pip install scipy
```

...i get an error :

```
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

...followed by the command line that ostensibly caused the error. if i cut/paste the command line to see what's causing the error, i get tonnes of output, including the following :

```
Building wheel for Cython (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Cython
```

so it seems whoever made the package has it calling gcc to actually *compile* a dependency -- cython, in this case -- which is actually already installed :

```
$ cython --version
Cython version 0.29.14
```

i see that the scipy package requires Cython>=0.29.13, but unfortunately pip doesn't seem to take this into account. not only is it somehow missing the fact that cython is already present, it's actually trying to compile a brand new one... @_@
[interestingly, the cython web site says the latest version is 0.28.5...]

FYI :

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

i've also tried downloading the archive from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy and extracting it, then tried to use pip locally :

```
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=. .
Looking in links: .
Processing /usr/local/src/scipy-1.4.1
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
.
.
.
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

so i found some windows binaries. trying to download them from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy, i am faced w/a `.whl` file. researching, i see that a `.whl` file is actually a self-contained wheel, installable w/pip. i try to do this :

```
pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=. scipy-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

...and i get

```
no such option: --use-wheel
```

then :

```
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=. *.whl
ERROR: scipy-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

so apparently the windows distrib isn't supported under cygwin.

does anyone have any experience w/this ?
any ideas on what else i could try ?

thanks.

Comment: It's hard to read what exactly is happening in your case, as so much is dependent on some system-paths not given. You are also trying to install a python3.8 wheel to your py3.6 install which will be rejected for sure. And also be careful about mixing different sources of builds (a pip install of numpy + a gohlke scipy for example). I would not recommend this.

Comment: I confirmed that cygwin's py won't be able to use prebuild wheels automatically. It seems you need to build it from source. This is potentially hard. Cygwin might help you with binaries of blas/lapack, the most annoying part. But i did not check if packages are available. Not sure, why you target cygwin. Maybe MSYS2 is a candidate. It does not have the latest scipy binaries, but a [recent one](https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=binpkg&q=scipy) (supporting py38) .

Comment: @sascha thanks for your reply! actually according to `python --version`, the python installed is `Python 3.8.0b4`. however, it seems the more important problem you point out is that these python packages need to be rebuilt from scratch... i've found and installed libblas and lapack, still running into problems. i'll keep hacking at it. thanks for your help.

Comment: My observation about the version clash was from `$ pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`. This pip is part of some python 3.6 for sure.

Comment: the list of available packages on cygwin is at https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html. Cygwin has its on python36-numpy package. I assume it is better to use still cygwin python-3.6 that is the default one and remove python-3.8 that is still incomplete as additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has its own packaging system and ~~there is already a scipy binary package for Cygwin~~. Update: I'm not at my computer so I'm not sure, but some googling suggests there might *not* be a python3-scipy package after all. See below...

When you installed Cygwin you probably went through the graphical installer which allows you to select packages to install in Cygwin. You can always install new packages by re-running the installer and selecting additional packages.

However, I find it easier in an existing Cygwin installation to use the command-line package installer [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/blob/master/readme.md).

You can install it by running

```
$ wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
$ install apt-cyg /usr/local/bin
```

Then run

```
$ apt-cyg install python3-scipy
```

and that's it.

If, per my update, that doesn't work, you can also build scipy from source but it takes a long time and requires a number of build dependencies installed. Off the top of my head I think at a minimum you should try:

```
$ apt-cyg install python3-cython python3-numpy python3-devel openblas-devel gcc gfortran
```

Then try

```
$ python3 -m pip install scipy
```

If that still doesn't work let me know and I'll add further updates. I've built scipy plenty of times on Cygwin so I know it works, but I'm writing this off the top of my head.

Currently PyPI doesn't support uploading binary wheels for Cygwin. I've been meaning to get that changed but I haven't had a chance yet. But in the meantime many popular scientific Python packages already have packages in the Cygwin package repository.

Comment: thanks for the great tips. yes, i was using the gui installer, but i'll be using apt-cyg from now on! to confirm, no, there is currently no scipy package available for cygwin ; it doesn't appear in the gui installer, and running `apt-cyg install python3-scipy` returns `Unable to locate package python3-scipy`.
of the packages you mention above, pip  says all were installed except gfortran and python3-devel. i installed python3-devel, but apt-cyg couldn't find gfortran. i do have libgfortran4. many errors on `python3 -m pip install scipy` [see below].

Comment: `python3 -m pip install scipy` - for starters, it looks like it's trying to recreate numpy. i get `Collecting numpy>=1.13.3`, but numpy is already installed [v. 1.16.2], and it fetches numpy-1.18.0.zip. it then tries to build and compile a whole lot of stuff for numpy. it also looks for a number of different fortran compilers, but doesn't look for `gcc-fortran` [which is installed].

Comment: Right, gcc-fortran is what I meant. It should work. You might be missing some other dependencies but I'm not sure. It usually works fine for me.

Comment: If for some reason it keeps insisting on reinstalling Numpy (it shouldn't...) you can try options to `pip` like `--no-deps`

Comment: It would be nice if this question was updated to a definitive answer, and removing the parts that are wrong (e.g. recommending installing a non-existent cygwin package).